# Webform: Enabling a contact to register for multiple participants

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I'm trying to create a webform that has one contact and allows the selection of multiple "tickets" to an event that we don't need contacts for. The spaces are free if that makes any difference.

This in civi would then count multiple participants per contact as it currently does when registering for events directly through civi.

Thanks,
Stuart